# When using a non thread safe class is a viable design to create multiple objects and pass it into each thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

Say I have class A which is not thread safe, and I want to launch a bunch of threads with class B, is passing a new instance of class A to each thread of class B a good design choice, since if I passed one instance of class A to all of them there would be concurrency issues?

```
@NotThreadSafe
class A {
...
}

class B extends Thread {
   private A a;

   B(A a) {
       this.a = a;
   }
}

class C {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            A a = new A();
            B b = new B(a);
            b.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes `A` not thread safe? Is it that it's mutable and `B` changes the state of `a`?

Comment: You need to provide an implementation of A. The question is too abstract and won't find a specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It pretty much depends on the characteristics of class A.

In general, passing creating an instance of A per thread will solve (not solve, but rather eliminate) concurrency issues.
Assuming class A has some internal state (otherwise class A itself is supposed to be thread safe), each thread B will read/update different fields in memory that belong to its "own" object of class A, so no concurrency issue here, unless...

1. A is very "heavy" object and creating it will have a big performance / memory impact.
2. Using design of object per thread won't meet the functional requirements of the product. For example, you **have** to share something between threads (somthing = some common state) because if one thread B, say, has done some work and has updated that internal state, another thread B should be able to benefit from (be able to read) that state otherwise it will do that work again or do it in a wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have overridden `run` in the `B` class.  Your example doesn't make sense otherwise.  (The `start()` call would invoke `Thread::run` which returns immediately.  Ooops!)

Some terminology first.

- A *thread confined* object is an object is an object whose state is accessible to one and only one thread.
- If an object is thread confined, then it doesn't matter if the class is thread-safe or not.

(Depending on how broadly you define "state" of course.   Lets assume that the object's state is the closure of the object that the object's methods may access.  Or something like that.)

So what we have in your example is a non-thread-safe object `a` that is created in main and then used *solely* in a single child thread.

- Prior to the `start()` call, each `a` is thread confined to the main thread.  For this part of the program, thread-safety (of `A`) doesn't matter.
- Once control reaches the child thread's `run()` method, each `a` is thread confined to the child thread.  From then on, thread safety doesn't matter.

Now what about the `start()` call itself?

The Java Memory Model (JLS 17.4) specifies that there is a *happens-before* relationship between the call to `start()` in the main thread, and the call to `run()` in the child thread.  This happens-before ensures that writes to the `A` or `B` instances or anything else made by the main thread *prior to the `start()` call* are guaranteed to be visible to the child thread on / *after entering the `run` method body*.   This is a strong guarantee.  Any compliant Java 5.0 or later implementation will behave this way, on any platform.

However, changes made to the `A`, etc in the main thread *after* the `start()` call are not guaranteed to be visible to the child.  They may or may not be.  If that happens, your code is likely to be broken.  But the example code doesn't show it happening.

---

In summary, this approach is thread-safe.  Whether it is "viable" depends on whether your design meets the requirements.  For example, the `B` threads need to share state, this approach doesn't address that.

Finally, extending `Thread` is generally thought to be a bad idea.  A better idea would be to instantiate plain `Thread` instances, passing them a `Runnable` as a constructor parameter.  Alternatively, use an `ExecutorService` and let that take care of thread management.

Comment: Yeah my code implements run, I just omitted it for brevity.

Answer (score -1):

There is a big difference between using a single instance and a new instance each time. (Eg if the class represents a Person then, it's the difference between the same person or a different one every time. This makes the program outcome different between circumstances and this question therefore doesn't make sense.)

If we assume the class holds no data and therefore the program outcome will not change whether or not a single instance or multiple are used, then

> a good design choice, since if I passed one instance of class A to all
>   of them there would be concurrency issues

it would be a terrible design choice and not solve any concurrency issues, as the external data each class instance works on will still be the same and the threads will fight over the data.

To fix concurrency issues you must use synchronization.